# Prorgess bar for `New-MailboxExportRequest`

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to create a script that can export a user's mailbox to a PST, remotely (Exchange Server 2010 console is installed on the server we're running this from, and the module is loaded correctly). It's being done using a script so our L2 admins do not have to manually perform the task. Here's the MWE.

```
$UserID = Read-Host "Enter username"
$PstDestination = "\\ExServer\Share\$UserID.pst"
$Date = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddhhmmss"
$ExportName = "$UserID" + "$Date"
try { 
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $UserID -FilePath $PstDestination -Name $ExportName -ErrorAction Stop -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
# Loop through the process to track its status and write progress
do {
$Percentage = (Get-MailboxExportRequest -Name $ExportName | Get-MailboxExportRequestStatistics).PercentComplete
Write-Progress "Mailbox export is in progress." -Status "Export $Percentage% complete" -PercentComplete "$Percentage"
}
while ($Percentage -ne 100)
Write-Output "$UserID`'s mailbox has been successfully exported. The archive can be found at $PstDestination."
}
catch {
Write-Output "There was an error exporting the mailbox. The process was aborted."
}
```

The problem is, as soon as we initiate the export, the task gets `Queued`. Sometimes, the export remains queued for a very long time, and the script is currently unable to figure out when the task begins, and when it does, is unable to display the progress correctly. The export happens in the background, but the script remains stuck there. So anything after the export, does not get executed, and the whole thing then has to be done manually.

Please suggest a way to handle this?

I tried adding a wait timer and then a check to see if the export has begun. It didn't quite work as expected.

Comment: where you able to solve this ? can you shed more light here

Comment: Sure, the solution given by @bartekb worked. I've marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things. First one is more about performance/hammering Exchange with unnesacary requests in do/while loop. `Start-Sleep -Seconds 1` (or any other delay that makes sense depending on the mailbox size(s)) inside the loop is a must.

Second: rather than wait for job to start, just resume it yourself:

```
if ($request.Status -eq 'Queued') {
    $request | Resume-MailboxExportRequest
}
```